# better collection or better way to search within dictionary

Tags: c#

I need to store 2 key's (`true` and `false`) with their corresponding values (`1` and `2`).

```
Dictionary<bool, int> X = new Dictionary<bool, int>();
X.Add(true, 1);
X.Add(false, 2);
```

Is there any other better collection as only 2 key value pair?

Then for one of the external values bool true or false, I need to look for value for that key

```
int x = GetIntFromDictionary(X, true);

private static int GetIntFromDictionary(Dictionary<bool, int> dict, bool val)
{
    int v = 0;
    if (dict.ContainsKey(val))
    {
        v = dict[val];
    }

    return v;
}
```

What is the best way to lookup the value within a dictionary or other collection, if suitable?

Comment: would `val ? 1 : 2` not suffice?

Comment: Why storing it in *any* collection if you have only two options?

Comment: When all you want is to convert true to 1 and false to 2 for whatever reason then @Sayse suggestion is enough.

Comment: fine, but 1 and 2 is not fixed. 1 and 2 become 3,4 as well.

Comment: i need to store in collection as values 1,2 coming from external source

Comment: you can replace 1,2 with variables and save the incoming values in those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **only** possibilities for the key of type `bool` are `true` and `false`; that's why there's no need in `ContainsKey`, `TryGetValue`...

```
    Dictionary<bool, int> X = new Dictionary<bool, int>() {
      {true, 5},
      {false, -15},
    };

    Dictionary<bool, int> OtherX = new Dictionary<bool, int>() {
      {true, 123},
      {false, 456},
    };


    ...

    private static int GetIntFromDictionary(Dictionary<bool, int> dict, bool val) {
      return dict[val];
    }    

    ...

    int result1 = GetIntFromDictionary(X, true);
    int result2 = GetIntFromDictionary(X, false);
    int result3 = GetIntFromDictionary(OtherX, true);
    int result4 = GetIntFromDictionary(OtherX, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `val` isn't nullable, and you state that your "dictionary" only ever contains 2 keys, you don't need any collection, just set a ternary or if statement

```
private static int GetValue(bool val)
{
    return val ? 1 : 2;
}
```

Comment: fine, but 1 and 2 is not fixed. 1 and 2 become 3,4 as well.

Comment: i need to store in collection as values 1,2 coming from external source

Comment: @user584018 - Then you should update your question to fully explain the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private static int GetValue(Dictionary<bool, int> dict, bool val)
{
    int value;
    dict.TryGetValue(val, out value);

    return value;
}
```

It will return the associated value if exists, otherwise 0.

If 0 is legitimate value use the method `bool` return value

```
private static int GetValue(Dictionary<bool, int> dict, bool val)
{
    int value;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(val, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }

    return int.MinValue; // or any other indication
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If mapping true/false to an external value is your problem then I would do something like.

```
var mapping = new int[] { externalValueFalse, externalValueTrue};

private static int GetValue(bool val)
{
  return mapping[val ? 1 : 0];
}
```